# syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby, json, uri, net-http

I'm trying to write a simple program to parse JSON from the results of an API call. Very new to ruby and just can't figure this one out.

Here's all the code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "json"
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://api.chartbeat.com/live/recent/v3/?apikey=eaafffb9a735796b6edd50fd31eaab69&host=enactus.org")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)

if response.code == "200"
  result = JSON.parse(response.body)

  result.each do |doc|
    puts doc["id"] #reference properties like this
    puts doc # this is the result in object form    
    puts ""
    puts ""
  end
else
  puts "ERROR!!!"
end
```

Here's the output of running the program (chartbeat.rb):

```
chartbeat.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

The program comes verbatim from here with the url replaced: https://gist.github.com/timsavery/1657351

Comment: your code above works fine for me

Comment: You should not post your API-key here. Also it works for me (copy&pasting into irb)

Comment: yeah time to reset that API key :)

Comment: Try removing your ` result.each do |doc|` block and see what you get please.

Comment: Very strange. Copying it into irb works for me as well, but running it ('ruby chartbeat.rb') via the terminal gives me that result.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant tried it, yielded same results

Comment: are you running the right file? `cat chartbeat.rb` <- if you're unix based

Comment: Try removing the require rubygems

Comment: I know it's unwise to publicly share an API key but I generated this one just testing. Once I get this running I'll generate a new one for actual use.

Comment: Turns out I was editing one file in Sublime Text but running another. Still, I get an error running the correct file: "chartbeat.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting end-of-input"

Comment: Figured it out: I had made the edits @MichaelDurrant suggested but forgot to revert the program to its original state. Running it as is, at the correct location, works fine. Thanks everybody. I'm a n00b.

Comment: Vote to close as not reproducible with the code given :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like what you're doing is taking advantage of any of Net::HTTPs power, so I'd probably do it like this:

```
require "rubygems"
require "json"
require "open-uri"

response = open("http://api.chartbeat.com/live/recent/v3/?apikey=eaafffb9a735796b6edd50fd31eaab69&host=enactus.org").read

result = JSON.parse(response)

result.each do |doc|
  puts doc["id"] #reference properties like this
  puts doc # this is the result in object form
  puts ""
  puts ""
end
```

OpenURI is the basis of a lot of code that hits URLs, and is a great starting place.

If you want to trap exceptions raised, use something like:

```
begin
  response = open("http://api.chartbeat.com/live/recent/v3/?apikey=eaafffb9a735796b6edd50fd31eaab69&host=enactus.org").read
rescue Exception => e
  puts e.message
  exit
end
```

It could even be reduced to:

```
require "rubygems"
require "json"
require "open-uri"

JSON[
  open("http://api.chartbeat.com/live/recent/v3/?apikey=eaafffb9a735796b6edd50fd31eaab69&host=enactus.org").read
].each do |doc|
  puts doc["id"] #reference properties like this
  puts doc # this is the result in object form
  puts ""
  puts ""
end
```

But that might be too drastic.